# Encrypt Decrypt data in Java

Tags: java, rest

I have developed Rest web services in Java which takes Passwords and sensitive data from request body.
How can I decrypt these data from my side and request sender can also enrypt at their end in same way?

Comment: Check inbuilt java AES - refer https://www.baeldung.com/java-cipher-input-output-stream

Comment: Specifically encrypting / decrypting is a solved problem with multiple quality implementations available. In general, security is difficult. If you do this from scratch by yourself and don't have the relevant experience (sounds like you don't), it is likely you will mess this up. If you want to proceed - start thinking about secret key management.

Answer (score 1):

Basically by changing your design to use end-to-end encryption, via TLS.

In other words, you ensure that all your services can only be used the "https".

But that is a pretty broad topic, and details depend on the underlying framework your are using.  Here is some reading for [Spring/J2EE](https://www.taringamberini.com/en/blog/java/adding-encryption-to-a-restful-web-service/), and here with [Spring and Jersey](https://avaldes.com/jax-rs-security-using-json-web-encryption-jwe-with-jwsjwt-for-authentication-and-authorization/), or there for [Oracle WebLogic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/secure.htm#RESTF113).

Comment: Will "https" secure data without using any encrypting technique?

Comment: For request/return bodies. But honestly: you should study this in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use [jayspt](http://www.jasypt.org/) library for simple encrypt or decrpyt.

Here is the source code for encrypting data:

```
String seedValue = "11241313xyz";
String mySecretStringshhh = "#soIsc00l123";

StandardPBEStringEncryptor stringEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
stringEncryptor.setPassword(seedValue);
String encrypted= stringEncryptor.encrypt(mySecretStringshhh);
```

And for decryption:

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor stringEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
stringEncryptor.setPassword(seedValue);

String decryptedPassword = stringEncryptor.decrypt(encryptedpwdString);
```

Write a test case and have fun...

Further reference - http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-passwords.html

Comment: Is it totally secure? because I think there are out of the box JAVA cryptographic APIs. Which one is more secure?

Comment: @munnusingh "More secure" is a pointless term. Security is complicated and can't be assessed easily in such terms. But i agree with you: you typically prefer built-in technology over 3rd party libraries, at least for the Java side of things.